# Getting ID of outer element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

If I am dynamically generating HTML similar to this?

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="tab_pg_4">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-8"><span>Group5</span></a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="tab_pg_5">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-10"><span>Group4</span></a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="tab_pg_6">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-19"><span>Group8</span></a>
</li>
```

and I have a javascript variable which contains the string `Group4`

How do I console.log or alert `tab_pg_5`?

Comment: console.log($("li:contains('Group4')").attr("id"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jquery function [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest matching ancestor.

```js
var myVar = 'Group4';
console.log($('a[href^="#ui-tabs-"] span:contains("' + myVar + '")').closest('li').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice. With an `<ul>` around it, you can make the selector more specific.

```
var myId = 'Group4';
var elementId = $('li:contains(' + myId + ')').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add a click event and use closest

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var lid = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    alert(lid);
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yYDeq/)

Answer (score -1):

Oh yeah i totally missunderstand the question, so :

```
$('a span').each(function({ 
    if ((this).html() == 'Group 4'))
        var = $(this).parent().parent();
});
```

Comment: But I don't know the id, I want to find the id using the string `Group4`.